Applications of Egyptian products
Applications of Egyptian fractions
An Egyptian fraction is a representation of $a/b$ such that
$$\frac{a}{b} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{c_{n}} $$
with $c_{1} \leq c_{2} \leq c_{3} \leq \dots c_{N} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} .$ Often , though not necessarily , the $c_{i}$ are distinct.
One practical application of such Egyptian fractions is fair division. Suppose, for example, that one wants to divide $5$ pizzas equally among $8$ people. Then the Egyptian fraction
$$\frac{5}{8} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} $$
means that each diner gets half a pizza plus another eighth of a pizza, for example by splitting $4$ pizzas into $8$ halves, and the remaining pizza into $8$ eighths.
Another application of Egyptian fractions is that they provide solutions to rope-burning puzzles.
Egyptian products
In these questions, I propose the notion of a product analogue of such Egyptian (sum) fractions. These Egyptian products (*) are representations of fractions of the form $a/b$ where $b>a$, such that $$\frac{a}{b} = \prod_{k=1}^{K} \left(1-\frac{1}{a_{k}} \right) ,$$ and $a_{1} \leq a_{2} \leq a_{3} \leq \dots \leq a_{K} .$
Sometimes, these products are quite a bit shorter than their sum counterparts. For instance, we have \begin{align} \frac{80}{99} &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{396} . \\ &= \left(1-\frac{1}{9} \right) \left( 1-\frac{1}{11} \right). \end{align}
Solutions to diophantine equation
There are also cases where the Egyptian (sum) fraction is equal to its Egyptian product expansion.
Some examples include
\begin{align}
\frac{8}{15} &= \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \ \ \ \ + \ \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{5} \\
&= \left(1-\frac{1}{3} \right) \left( 1-\frac{1}{5} \right),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{391}{728} &= \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{3} \ \ \ \ \ + \ \ \ \  \frac{1}{7} \ \ \ \ + \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{24} \ \ \ \ \ + \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{52} \\
&= \left(1-\frac{1}{3} \right) \left( 1-\frac{1}{7} \right) \left(1-\frac{1}{24} \right) \left( 1-\frac{1}{52} \right).
\end{align}
Question

Applications of Egyptian fractions are many.
Are there any applications of Egyptian products?

Note
(*) Observe that this term is sometimes used to describe Engel expansions. These Egyptian products are something different.

Euler's Totient Function $\varphi(n)$, counting the number of numbers $0 < k < n$ where $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, is equal to $n$ times the Egyptian product of its distinct prime factors.

the egyptian product can also be used to generate very simplified "dice-rolling" methods for reaching particular probabilities: imagine having a three-sided die and a five-sided die (disregarding your geometric difficulties), each with one side having a black dot on it.  The probability that, rolling these dice together, no black dots show up, is 8/15.

While this is technically true , it is not a valid answer to the OP Question. You have taken $a/b=\Pi()$ to get $a=b\Pi()$ & then compared with Euler Totient function , which will match that format. OP is asking for the usefulness of writing some arbitrary number in that format.

Thank you for your answer - I especially like the application to dice-rolling!
